# (javascript)Is it possible to push an object in the array located inside another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, push

Is it possible to push an object in the array located inside another object? I really can't think of ways to do it.

I am doing [this project](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/node-path-javascript-todo-list) from The Odin Project. I have nowhere else to ask this question. Please kindly let me know if it's not allowed here. thanks.

and for clarification this is not an assignment, I am not graded for this I just simply want to move forward cause I've been frustratingly stuck at this project for almost a month now. You don't have to provide the answer. An article or reference on how to do it is okay and very much appreciated by me.

I want to push this

```
class Task {
  constructor(title, date, priority, desc) {
  this.title = title;
  this.date = date;
  this.priority = priority;
  this.desc = desc; 
  }
```

inside the array of the Project class

```
class Project {
  constructor(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.tasks = [];
  }
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment you need help with? ;-)

Comment: @michel404 no, i am actually doing a project from the odin project. been stuck with this for weeks i just want to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `Project` class add `addTask(task)` method. Something like:

```
addTask(task) {
    this.tasks.push(task);
}
```

Comment: To add an element in a JS array, you should use `push`, not `append` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push